# How to resolve Predicate is not allowed (closed shape) validation error

Tags: validation, rdf, shacl

I am using https://shacl.org/playground/

I have the following Shape Graph:

```
@prefix hr: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#> .
@prefix d:  <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

hr:ClassShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetSubjectsOf rdf:type;

    sh:or (
        [                
            sh:path rdf:type ;
            sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
            sh:hasValue rdfs:Class;
        ]
        [                
            sh:path rdf:type ;
            sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
            sh:hasValue rdf:Property;
        ]
    );

    sh:closed true ;
.
```

I have the following Data Graph

```
@prefix hr: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#> .
@prefix d:  <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

#### Regular RDFS modeling ####

hr:Employee a rdfs:Class .

hr:Another a rdfs:Class .

hr:name
   rdf:type rdf:Property ; .

hr:hireDate
   rdf:type rdf:Property ; .

hr:jobGrade
   rdf:type rdf:Property ; .
```

I want to verify that every node which declares a rdf:type has a value of either rdfs:Class or rdf:Property.

I am getting the following validation errors:

```
[
    a sh:ValidationResult ;
    sh:resultSeverity sh:Violation ;
    sh:sourceConstraintComponent sh:ClosedConstraintComponent ;
    sh:sourceShape hr:ClassShape ;
    sh:focusNode hr:Employee ;
    sh:resultPath rdf:type ;
    sh:value rdfs:Class ;
    sh:resultMessage "Predicate is not allowed (closed shape)" ;
] .
[
    a sh:ValidationResult ;
    sh:resultSeverity sh:Violation ;
    sh:sourceConstraintComponent sh:ClosedConstraintComponent ;
    sh:sourceShape hr:ClassShape ;
    sh:focusNode hr:Another ;
    sh:resultPath rdf:type ;
    sh:value rdfs:Class ;
    sh:resultMessage "Predicate is not allowed (closed shape)" ;
] .
[
    a sh:ValidationResult ;
    sh:resultSeverity sh:Violation ;
    sh:sourceConstraintComponent sh:ClosedConstraintComponent ;
    sh:sourceShape hr:ClassShape ;
    sh:focusNode hr:name ;
    sh:resultPath rdf:type ;
    sh:value rdf:Property ;
    sh:resultMessage "Predicate is not allowed (closed shape)" ;
] .
[
    a sh:ValidationResult ;
    sh:resultSeverity sh:Violation ;
    sh:sourceConstraintComponent sh:ClosedConstraintComponent ;
    sh:sourceShape hr:ClassShape ;
    sh:focusNode hr:hireDate ;
    sh:resultPath rdf:type ;
    sh:value rdf:Property ;
    sh:resultMessage "Predicate is not allowed (closed shape)" ;
] .
[
    a sh:ValidationResult ;
    sh:resultSeverity sh:Violation ;
    sh:sourceConstraintComponent sh:ClosedConstraintComponent ;
    sh:sourceShape hr:ClassShape ;
    sh:focusNode hr:jobGrade ;
    sh:resultPath rdf:type ;
    sh:value rdf:Property ;
    sh:resultMessage "Predicate is not allowed (closed shape)" ;
] .
```

I am not sure why or what I need to do to resolve them. I believe all of the validation errors are related, so the solution to one should provide the solution to the rest.

What should my Shape file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused the OR-statement, here is a working example following the [SHACL docs on sh:or](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#OrConstraintComponent)

```
@prefix hr: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/humanResources#> .
@prefix d:  <http://learningsparql.com/ns/data#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

hr:ClassShape
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetSubjectsOf rdf:type;

  sh:property [
    sh:path rdf:type ;
    sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
    sh:or (
      [sh:hasValue rdfs:Class;]
      [sh:hasValue rdf:Property;]
    )
  ]; 

  sh:closed true ;
.
```

Comment: How did I confuse the the OR statement? I am not sure I understand why your solution is correct.

Comment: You added `sh:or([sh:path rdf:type; A] [sh:path rdf:type; B])`, but it is supposed to be `sh:path rdf:type; sh:or(A, B)`.

Comment: But that is not an answer: It is supposed to be ? Why ? What's wrong with his original modeling, that is what need to be explained. It is unfortunate because this is a very interesting question

Comment: To me there is something about how shacl handle sh:or and sh:path where that. sh:path is actually the same.

Comment: Thanks for pushing this again. I double-checked and found that the actual issue is the `sh:targetSubjectsOf rdf:type;` part, as it also targets `hr:Employee a rdfs:Class` etc. I verified it at the new SHACL playground at https://shacl-playground.zazuko.com/ with the OP's data graph & shape graph, but without the line `sh:targetSubjectsOf rdf:type;`.

Answer (score 0):

sh:closed only looks at directly declared properties of the shape. So it should work if you state

```
hr:ClassShape
    sh:property [
        sh:path rdf:type ;
    ] ;
    sh:closed true ;
    ...
```

Closed shapes do not consider sh:or or other complex structures, see the details at

https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#ClosedConstraintComponent

Comment: I am not sure what my Shape file should look like to resolve these validation errors. I am not sure how your provided Shape validates what mine does. Can the validation errors be resolved and can I still validate what I want to validate?